# Passing current_scopes from the has_scopes gem as a param

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, scopes, has-scope

I've been struggling with this problem for several days. I'm a lawyer and I'm building a Q&A type site for legal advice (yups, I'm a relative newbie to rails :-)).

I want users to be able to filter questions by category (i.e. company law, IP etc etc) and then be able to sort them on a secondary basis by most recent or popular etc.

I've tried a number of approaches and ultimately, I've been unable to find a way to pass the current category selected as another param when trying to sort by recent, popular etc.

I've just started using the has_scopes gem and I see from the documentation that there is a method called 'current_scopes'. I can't seem to work out how to pass current_scopes in the view as a param where the recent or popular scope can then be called on it. Logically, I'm assuming that current_scopes needs to be assigned to a variable in the controller, but again, can't work out how to then pass this in the view as a param.

My current code:

## post.rb

```
    has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
    belongs_to :user, :counter_cache => true
    belongs_to :category, :counter_cache => true

    scope :recent,      ->{ order("created_at DESC")}
    scope :popular,     -> { order("comments_count DESC")}
    scope :unanswered,  -> {where(comments_count: 0)}
    scope :category, -> category_id {where(:category_id => category_id)}
```

## posts_controller.rb

```
  has_scope :category 
  has_scope :recent, :type => :boolean
  has_scope :popular, :type => :boolean
  has_scope :unanswered, :type => :boolean

  def index
    @posts = @q.result.includes(:comments).order("created_at DESC") #@q comes from using Ransack gem and applying in the application controller
    @posts = apply_scopes(Post).all
    @scope = current_scopes
```

## _sidebar.html.erb

```
    <h3>Filter by: </h3>
     <ul class="side-nav fixed" role="navigation" title="Link List">
       <li role="menuitem"><%= link_to "Show all", root_path %></li>
       <li role="menuitem"><%= link_to "Corporate", category: 1 %></li>
       <li role="menuitem"><%= link_to "Intellectual Property", category: 2 %></li>
       <li role="menuitem"><%= link_to "Employment", category: 3 %></li>
       <li role="menuitem"><%= link_to "Commercial", category: 4 %></li>
       <li role="menuitem"><%= link_to "Real Estate", category: 5 %></li>
       <li role="menuitem"><%= link_to "Venture Capital", category: 6 %></li>
     </ul>
    
    <h3>Sort by:</h3>
      <li> <%= link_to "Most Recent", :recent => true %> </li>
      <li> <%= link_to "Most Popular", :popular => true  %></li>
      <li> <%= link_to "Unanswered", :unanswered => true %></li>
```

Thank you and really appreciate any assistance with this matter.

Comment: I'm not a fan of using third party libraries inside controllers: controllers behaviours are usually quite specific and you end up to spend too much time trying to understand what's wrong and adjusting functionalities to your fits (Devise, I hate you more than how much I love you). Are you already coupled to `has_scope` or you could get rid of it?

Comment: Hiya, not coupled to has_scopes at all. This was my third strategy after effort 1 (using just scopes) and effort 2 (using a separate category and filter model) failed. So basically, happy to get rid of it, if it helps solve the problem! :-)

Comment: Very good, thank's!!!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else looking for the answer to this question, the `current_scopes` value is only available after `apply_scopes` has been called. The issue is documented [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/has_scope/issues/72).